# Error with implementing font in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, fonts

Image below describes my problem
[image]

All fonts: Rubik Mono One and Kumar One are downloaded from https://fonts.google.com/, but the second - https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Kumar+One?query=kumar+one - is not working. i don`t understand, which trouble is with it, if anyone know i will very appreciate. Thanks.

Comment: All fine, i found not issue, but another way, how to solve it, thanks you all!)